# Определить, с какого экрана пришёл пользователь

Tags: swift

В приложении есть несколько экранов, и на двух из них есть кнопка, которая ведёт на третий.

После действий на этом третьем экране (к примеру, заполнить поле и нажать кнопку "отправить") пользователь должен вернуться на предыдущий экран. Проблема в том, что переходы между экранами принадлежат одному и тому же Segue Class, и передать через него какую-то переменную я не смогу.

Может быть, есть какой-нибудь способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сториборде указываете для своего segue 'id', и во viewController пишете метод `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`.
В этом методе вы проверяете происходит ли нужный вам segue по id, и далее можете определить какой контроллер будет следующим через `segue.destinationViewController`. А в этом контроллере, вам надо создать переменную, где будете хранить откуда пришли и присвоить ее например так:

```
segue.destinationViewController.parent = self
```

Comment: Не совсем. У меня все экраны созданы в storybord`e (понимаю что это не совсем правильно, но пока другого варианта не было) и переходы у меня осуществленны простым "перетягиванием" с кнопки на другой экран. То есть не совсем программно.

Comment: исправил ответ.

Comment: Cпасибо, получилось :)